# Create custom event

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dropdown list filled with items. The situation is, I am getting all the items from database without filtering it on `deletedFlag` because if item is deleted (set deletedFlag) but was already selected at some point I want to retrieve and display that and ask user to change it before he updates the record. That is being done by validation, no issue. But won't it be good to remove that item once user has expanded dropdown so there will be no confusion whether to select it or not? I did it using jQuery and it's looking just good. But can I do that in `C#`? May be creating custom event that will be fired when dropdown is expanded? Could be please guide me into this?

Comment: In my personal opinion you are not doing it right. You should filter the selectable items to be correct ones and select none for deleted items. In this case you can inform user in some other place (beside the dropdown itself maybe) what was the previously selected item.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear on how the data is bound to the DropDownList, but you can filter before binding using Linq.

Example with a `DataTable`

```
DataTable dataTable = Common.LoadFromDB();

DropDownList1.DataSource = dataTable.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<bool>("deletedFlag") == false).CopyToDataTable();
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

Example with a `List`

```
List<myClass> list = new List<myClass>();

DropDownList1.DataSource = list.Where(x => x.deletedFlag == false);
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```